# how to count number of elements in a list in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This might be pretty simple but my program is just a movie ticket booking:

My list is (for example):

```
bookings=[["Sam", 1, "titanic", "morning", "Stit1"],
          ["Bill", 2, "titanic", "evening", "Btit2"],
          ["Kik", 2, "lionking", "afternoon", "Klio2"]]
```

I want to print how many people are (for example) going to watch titanic. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
sum(b[2] == 'titanic' for b in bookings)
```

This creates a generator over `bookings`, then sums those with "titanic".

Note the implicit treatment of `True` and `False` as 1 and 0, respectively.

Comment: I think that in view of what is going on "under the hood" here, it would be worth saying some more about *how* this works, in terms of how `True` and `False` boolean values are treated in integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

You want only number or names also? Anyway, like this you getting list with all the people who going to watch 'Titanic' and you can easily get length of it

```
bookings=[["Sam", 1, "titanic", "morning", "Stit1"], ["Bill", 2, "titanic", "evening", "Btit2"], ["Kik", 2, "lionking", "afternoon", "Klio2"]]
count = [item for item in bookings if 'titanic' in item]
print(len(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary with movie names as keys and value being the total count. Something like this

```py
ticket_count = {}
for booking in bookings:
    ticket_count[booking[2]] = ticket_count.get(booking[2], 0) + 1
```

I am assuming that movie name is always third element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a sum of `1` for each relevant booking.

Only the third field is relevant in deciding which bookings to include, so you should use it (i.e. `booking[2]` here). If you look indiscriminately at all of the elements, then it might happen to work in most cases, but you could encounter problems if the movie name also appears in a different field, e.g. [Morning (film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morning_(film)).

The following method does not rely on performing arithmetic using boolean values.

```
sum(1 for booking in bookings if booking[2] == "titanic")
```